# How to select an element when a sibling is not present?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a structure like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child-1"></div>
    <div class="child-2"></div>
    <div class="child-3"></div>
    <div class="child-4"></div>
    <div class="child-5"></div>
</div>
```

I want to target `.child-4` only when `.child-2` is not a child of the same parent, without knowing the order of children, but the `.child-2` would never come after `.child-4`.

Comment: Can't have complex conditionals like this with css. You would have to use javascript. What's the reason for this kind of selection ?

Comment: In a similar structure, `.child-2` (as a div for title) has fixed position and so to avoid overlap, `.child-4` must have a `padding-top` value. Sometimes when `.child-2` would not be used, `.child-4` should not have the `padding-top` anymore. I think CSS really needs this kind of targeting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The classic CSS approach to such problems is to write a general case, then a more specialized case, where in this situation you would override the general case:

```css
/* case where there may or may not be a preceding child-2 */
.child-4            { color: red; }

/* case where there IS a preceding child-2 */
.child-2 ~ .child-4 { color: inherit; }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child-1">child1</div>
    <div class="child-2">child2</div>
    <div class="child-3">child3</div>
    <div class="child-4">child4</div>
    <div class="child-5">child5</div>
</div>

<br/>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child-1">child1</div>
    <div class="child-3">child3</div>
    <div class="child-4">child4</div>
    <div class="child-5">child5</div>
</div>
```

This uses the [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors), represented by a tilde (`~`).

Comment: And this is only made possible due to the condition that ".child-2 would never come after .child-4"

Comment: Yes! That was exactly what I need. Thank you @torazaburo and @BoltClock♦